# Bitcoinj will not compile onto Nexus 5 with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, nexus-5, bitcoinj

I am building an app using Bitcoinj and I am trying to run it on a Nexus 5. When using grade to build Bitcoinj - compile 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.12' - and subsequently running the app on the phone, I receive this error...

**"Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]"**

Does anyone have any idea why this is, or how to fix it?

Thanks,

Dan.

Comment: Are you running it on a virtual device or a physical?

Comment: I am running it on a physical device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When trying to run an android app that uses the BitcoinJ library for Nexus 5, with the latest android version 5.0 (Lollipop)
you will get this error message "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS".
The main reason is that you are trying to install an app that has native libraries and it doesn't have a native library for your cpu architecture.

The native library that did the problem was Scrypt.jar so I excluded it

```
    compile('com.google:bitcoinj:0.11.3') {
    exclude module: 'scrypt'
}
```

and instead of using

```
com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCrypt;
```

just use another scrypting library for instance,

```
org.spongycastle.crypto.generators.SCrypt;
```

Good Luck

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "use `org.spongycastle.crypto.generators.SCrypt`". My problem is that all the `bitcoinj` related files containing `com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCrypt` are locked in Android Studio and I can't change them.

Comment: @Anton you cannot change compiled files/libraries using android studio (unless you use NDK to re-compile) AFAIK.
Another solution is to rewrite specific files that uses _lambdaworks.crypto.SCrypt_ and just replace the import to _org.spongycastle.crypto.generators.SCrypt_.