# Android: No Matching ABI's

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, bitcoinj

**Problem:**

I cannot install my app on my HTC One M7 or any emulators while using Android Studio. Before the upgrade to 5.0.2 (from 4.4.?) it worked fine. Error message that I am receiving is INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS.

**Attempts:**

- I have tried and tested [Apk Splits](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits) to target armeabi-v7a. I have tried toggling universal apk with this option as well.
- I have tried following [other's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk) trouble with this problem and that has not helped.
- I have tried compiling with x86 through the above splitting method
- I have tried cleaning and rebuilding my project
- I have tried restarting Android Studio
- I have uninstalled the old version of the application after the 5.0.2 update

At this point I have no idea what to do to fix this issue

**Update**

1. I have created a brand new application and it seems to work fine with no splitting at all. Will update more when I find a better temporary fix
2. Possible cause: I am using bitcoinj library for my project and once I include this in my dependencies I get the above error

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Only the typical INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Comment: Update, I found a solution and it was due to bitcoinj and the recent Lollipop update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution has been found. The problem was due to my bitcoinj library and updating to Lollipop. You can [view this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28924959/3288623) which lead me to my success.